# Running a custom script in Hudson

Tags: hudson

I have a project which is managed by Hudson.  Recently I have written a simple batch script (in windows) which backs up the repository.  The idea is to have it run according to a schedule.  I wanted to integrate that into Hudson, not the project.  I had a look at the Hudson doco + googling around on that topic, but it seems there is no straight answer for it.  The closest thing I saw was the Execute Windows batch command, which appears to run a project rather than just a custom made script.

Is there a way to run just a script in Hudson?

TIA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are running hudson in a Linux server, but it should be relatively the same thing…

Under the build category in the configuration, there should be an execute shell command text box. It accepts all kind of CLI commands… It should typically run commands like cd folder_name or dir…

You could create a new job in Hudson and use the execute shell text box to do something like:

cd folder_of_backup_script

backup_script

Comment: I noticed the execute shell command text box under the Build section as well.  I also have a proper project build within that section, but it is under Build a Visual Studio project or solution using MSBuild.  Just wondering whether there is an order of execution within the build and whether conditions can be set on the different build steps?  Thanks.

Comment: @BeraCim: I've done this often and have always built solutions first and then executed commands afterward. As for conditions on the build steps, I don't think you can set any. However, if one of the steps fails, the steps that follow will not be executed.